# Split string with '+ 'and search whether all the strings exist in one row in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table **Rules** with 2 columns:

1. RID
2. RuleValue

`DECLARE @RuleType VARCHAR(MAX)= 'DDDD+FFFF' ;`

I want to split and search the above variable `'DDDD+FFFF'` in `rulevalue` column.

Below image is the rules table:

[image]

after splitting and searching in `rulevalue` column the output should be as below:

[image]

Comment: Can anyone try to answer this ?

Comment: Please check out the guidelines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order does not matter you can create a condition from your variable and then use it with a `like` filter in your `where` clause:

```
declare @Rules  table (RID int, RuleValue varchar(50))

insert into @Rules
values 
 (1,'DDDD+FFFF')
,(2,'DDDD+EEEE+FFFF')
,(3,'BBBB+CCCC')
,(4,'BBBB+DDDD')
,(5,'CCCC+EEEE')
,(6,'BBBB+DDDD')

DECLARE @RuleType VARCHAR(MAX)= 'DDDD+FFFF' ;

select *
from @Rules
where RuleValue like '%' + replace(@RuleType, '+','%') + '%'
```

Results:

[image]

---

*Edit after comment from OP*

If order matters, then the solution is a bit trickier.

```
declare @Rules table (RID int, RuleValue varchar(50))

insert into @Rules
values 
 (1,'DDDD+FFFF')
,(2,'DDDD+EEEE+FFFF')
,(3,'BBBB+CCCC')
,(4,'BBBB+DDDD')
,(5,'CCCC+EEEE')
,(6,'BBBB+DDDD')

DECLARE @RuleType VARCHAR(MAX)=  'DDDD+FFFF+EEEE' ;

--define a table variable to hold every component of the rule type
declare @splittedRules table (SplittedRule nvarchar(max))

--fill the table variable with each component of the rule type
--since you use SQL Server 2012 you must use xml syntax to split the string
insert into @splittedRules
SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') as SplittedRule
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@RuleType, '+', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
) AS A
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)

--now you can see if each rule matches a single component of the rule type
;with compare as 
(
    select 
        r.RID
        ,r.RuleValue
        ,spl.SplittedRule 
        , case when CHARINDEX(spl.SplittedRule, r.RuleValue) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as ok 
    from 
        @Rules as r 
            cross apply 
        @splittedRules spl
)
--finally you can perform a group by checking 
--which rule matches all the components of the rule type
select
    RID, RuleValue   
from 
    compare
group by 
    RID, RuleValue
having 
    sum (ok)=(select count(*) from @splittedRules)
order by RID
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Hi, to some extent this is what i want. if @RuleType = 'DDDD+FFFF+EEEE'  the  we should get 'DDDD+EEEE+FFFF' as output, is this possible ?

Comment: @MounikaVadeghar yes it is possible, see updated answer